# When pipes are in place and have overwritten stdout and stderr, where does printf go?

Tags: c, pipe, printf, io-redirection

I have set up pipes to redirect stderr and stdout. When I use printf, does it send data to stdout or to stream 1?

If it sends it to stdout, how can I instead configure it to send data to stream 1?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

printf always sends data to stdout. If you have redirected stdout using a pipe, it will go to the process that stdout is being piped to.

And stream 1 (assuming you mean the stream associated with file descriptor 1) *is* stdout, unless you are doing something *really* weird (in which case, stop)

Answer (score 3):

> When I use printf, does it send data to stdout or to stream 1?

The `printf` function sends data to `stdout`. Since you have redirected `stdout` it now points to a file other than your console. `printf` doesn't care what it is, it just keeps writing as long as it can.

> If it sends it to stdout, how can I instead configure it to send data to stream 1?

So, no you don't need to do anything special -- it is taken care of automatically.

Answer (score 2):

I think your understanding of the layers involved is a little bit misguided.

The C runtime's `printf` uses `FILE *stdout`, which (unless you use `freopen` or similar) is effectively equivalent to `fdopen(1, "w")`: that is, buffered output on file descriptor #1.

Normally, when you run `my_program`, file descriptor #1 is attached to the terminal.  When you run `my_program > file`, file descriptor #1 is attached to `file` *before* your program even starts running.  So `printf`, writing to `stdout`, which (unless you change it) scribbles to file descriptor #1, will print to the file and not the terminal.

Nothing outside of your program cares about your buffered I/O or what you do with your own `stdout`.